# OpenCV Error - Core.hpp header must be compiled as C++

Tags: ios, swift, opencv

I have tried `Core.hpp, Base.hpp header must be compiled as C++` error.
I have BITCODE set as `NO`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

@interface OpenCV : NSObject
    /// Converts a full color image to grayscale image with using OpenCV.
+ (nonnull UIImage *)cvtColorBGR2GRAY:(nonnull UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

In my `OpenCVSample.mm` I have included `#import "OpenCV.h` in header.

Git: https://github.com/n1tesh/OpenCV-Demo

Comment: .mm files should be complied as objective c++ source in the inspector.

Comment: @Jack Yes. Have changed Type to `Objective-C++ Source` but still the same error.

Comment: In build setting search Build Active Architecture Only and set to NO

Comment: Show your Bridging header file

Comment: @JonSnow Bridging Header file - `#import "OpenCV.h"` . And tried Build Active Architecture Only - `NO` but still same error.

Comment: Do you have .PCH file added ?

Comment: @JonSnow No, what is that ?

Comment: @Nitesh ignore then , Check this C++ Standard Library: libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)

Comment: @JonSnow Tried that now but error.

Comment: Ohh man, final try can be  check whether   libc++.tbd  added to the framework , Other linker flag add -lc++

Comment: Added demo on GIT https://github.com/n1tesh/OpenCV-Demo

Comment: I have downloaded project but i have pod erros you can try this link https://computer-vision-talks.com/2012-06-23-opencv-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a precompile header file. Create a `PrefixHeader.pch` file *at the same folder with the .xcodeproj file* with content:

```
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
// include other opencv2 headers if needed.
#endif

#endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */
```

Then go to Project's Build Settings, search for Prefix Header and set it to `PrefixHeader.pch`.

Additionally, if you want to call bridge `MMOpenCVHelper.h` to your swift code, it has to be Objective-C++ only. Put anything OpenCV, or standard C++, in `MMOpenCVHelper.mm`. For example:

**`MMOpenCVHelper.h`**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// These two headers god to mm file
// #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
// #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


@interface MMOpenCVHelper : NSObject
+ (UIImage *) applyOpenCVTo: (UIImage*) uiImage;

// these methods have to be in mm file, hence private
// + (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat;
// + (cv::Mat)cvMatFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
// + (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
// + (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
// + (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image;


@end
```

And **`MMOpenCVHelper.mm`**:

```
#import "MMOpenCVHelper.h"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

@implementation MMOpenCVHelper

// implementation of public methods:
+ (UIImage *) applyOpenCVTo: (UIImage*) uiImage{
    cv::Mat cvFrame = [MMOpenCVHelper cvMatFromAdjustedUIImage: uiImage];
    // do something with cvFrame using OpenCV
    cv::Mat ret = cvFrame.clone();

    return [MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat: ret];
}

// Implementations of the conversion functions:
+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat{
    // do something here
    return uiImage;
}

+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatGrayFromAdjustedUIImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

Later, in `SomeSwiftFile.swift` you can do (please verify this since I'm not very familiar with Swift):

```
let UIImage * processedImage = MMOpenCVHelper.applyOpenCVTo(uiImage);
```

Comment: But this won't work if you want to inherit a OpenCV class.