# Could not build module 'opencv2' , when using OpenCV in Swift Project

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, xcode, opencv

I have added **opencv** framework through **cocoapods**. I added required [frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR20x.png) to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** as well.

As, I am using Swift. So, I made a bridging header with "**Wrapper**" NSObject in Objective C. Problem is that when I try to import these in **Wrapper.h**, it gives me error

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
```

Error is:

```
Could not build module 'opencv2'
```

Where as if I import them in **Wrapper.mm** they work fine. Kindly tell me how to use them in header file. As I need to call a few variables from header file.

Answer (score 1):

When bridging header files to Swift, the files have to be pure Objective-C++. So you cannot include any opencv headers in `Wrapper.h`, they have to go in `Wrapper.mm`. For more detail how to write and use a wrapper, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292620/opencv-error-core-hpp-header-must-be-compiled-as-c/46294263#46294263).