# iOS - Core hpp header must be compiled with c++

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

First at all, I have researched about this issued in a long times and I tried:

- Rename .h -> .hpp
- create prefix header

but still not working.

I use Swift for my project and I install OpenCV via CocoaPods:

```
pod 'OpenCV', '~> 3.3'
```

It works fine, but when I try to `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` in header file it give me issues

> core.hpp:49:4: Core.hpp header must be compiled as C++

`YourEmoji-Prefix.pch`

```
#ifndef YourEmoji_Prefix_pch
#define YourEmoji_Prefix_pch

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#endif /* YourEmoji_Prefix_pch */
```

`Wrapper.hpp`

```
#pragma once


#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#endif
```

Please give me any idea to fix this. Thank you so much.

Comment: This seems like a linker/compiler error/problem.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541268/can-i-have-swift-objective-c-c-and-c-files-in-the-same-xcode-project/32546879#32546879 I think you need a wrapper in order to use them in swift

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Yes, I got that error in wrapper.h file

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you put some C++ code or link `opencv` headers in header files. For more detail, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292620/opencv-error-core-hpp-header-must-be-compiled-as-c/46294263#46294263).

Comment: I tried with Prefix Header but it still not works. :(

Comment: Post your related files (Prefix Header, wrapper.h, calls to wrapper.h..)

Comment: Move include opencv2/core/core.hpp to wrapper.hpp, put it to wrapper.cpp.

Comment: I will work, but I want to put it in .hpp file to declare some public function.

Comment: You simply can’t. Everything in headers must be pure Objective-C++, that’s why they call it wrapper.

Comment: Then how to inherit from a OpenCV class?